# How to download, unzip and read data to a csv using Scrapy

Tags: python, pandas, scrapy

I am experiencing issues downloading a list of zip files locally using Scrapy

**Code**

```
    def custom_parse(self, response):
        self.logger.info(response.url)
        links = response.xpath("//a[contains(@href, '.zip')]/@href").getall()

        for link in links:
            local_path = self.download_file(self.configs.get('ingestion').get('source_url') + link)
            zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(local_path)
            zip_csv_files = [file_name for file_name in zip_file.namelist() if file_name.endswith(".txt") and "pre" not in file_name]
            with zip_file.open(zip_csv_files, "r") as data_bytes:
                df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(data_bytes.read()), dtype=object)
            df = pd.read_csv(local_path)
            df = self.standardize(df)
            for k, row in df.iterrows():
                yield dict(row) 

    def standardized(self, df):
        df.columns = [col.lower().strip().replace(" ", "_") for col in df.columns]
        df = df.fillna('')
        return df
```

**EDIT: Error output**

```
   zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(local_path)
  File "/home/deployer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/zipfile.py", line 1222, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "/home/deployer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/zipfile.py", line 1289, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

I am trying to scrape this webpage: https://www.sec.gov/dera/data/financial-statement-data-sets.html of all the zip files listed under 'Data Downloads'. Each zip file contains four .txt files: num.txt, pre.txt, tag.txt, sub.txt. I want to scrape all of the files, besides 'pre.txt', into a csv. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can see the format of the file names, and you can see the beginning and ending years.  Why screw with `scrapy` at all?  Just do `requests` calls in a loop to download them.

Comment: I am working on an ingestion framework that solely uses scrapy to scrape data. Would you happen to see in my current implementation of where the issue might be occurring?

Comment: Is that really the entire error? There is nothing else?

Comment: Added additional error output. Please see the edited version.